# Is there a function like String#scan, but returning array of MatchDatas?

Tags: ruby

I need a function to return all matches of a regexp in a string *and* positions at which the matches are found (I want to highlight matches in the string).

There is String#match that returns MatchData, but only for the first match.

Is there a better way to do this than something like

```
matches = []
begin
  match = str.match(regexp)
  break unless match
  matches << match
  str = str[match.end(0)..-1]
  retry
end
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you just need to iterate over the MatchData objects you can use Regexp.last_match in the scan-block, like:

```
string.scan(regex) do
  match_data = Regexp.last_match
  do_something_with(match_data)
end
```

If you really need an array, you can use:

```
require 'enumerator' # Only needed for ruby 1.8.6
string.enum_for(:scan, regex).map { Regexp.last_match }
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about Regexp.last_match

Answer (score 2):

Do you really need the position or is it enough to replace the matches on the fly?

```
s="I'mma let you finish but Beyonce had one of the best music videos of all time!"
s.gsub(/(Beyonce|best)/, '<b>\1</b>')
```

> => "I'mma let you finish but **Beyonce** had one of the **best** music videos of all time!"

Comment: Nah, I only know what needs to be highlighted after the string is parsed and analyzed.

Comment: It sure looks like you are using Regexp for the parsing and so does gsub.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [captures](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/MatchData.html#method-i-captures) method on a successful match.

```
"foobar".match(/(f)(oobar)/).captures
```

=> ["f,""oobar"]

Answer (score 0):

I think at least you can enhance your code a bit:

```
matches = []
while(match = str.match(regexp)) 
  matches << match
  str = match.post_match
end
```