# Looking for Regexp#match_all

Tags: ruby

I've been trying to find something like this in the docs, but failed. What I want is to iterate over regular expression matches in a string, and passing `MatchData` to the block.

- There's `Regexp#match`, but it only finds one match;
- There's `String#scan`, but the block receives only the captures array or the match string, not full `MatchData`. This especially sucks with Oniguruma, as you lose the named capture capability.
- There's also `Regexp::last_match`, so I could actually go the `scan` route, but it seems ugly and inelegant.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Is there a function like String#scan, but returning array of MatchDatas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444778/is-there-a-function-like-stringscan-but-returning-array-of-matchdatas)

It looks like your best bet is to use `String#scan` and `Regexp.last_match`.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid that would be the answer. Inelegant, especially given that no monkey business is needed in case of a single match.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are missing something. From the MatchData documentation:

> MatchData is the type of the special variable $~, and is the type of
>   the object returned by Regexp#match and Regexp.last_match. It
>   encapsulates **all the results of a pattern match**, results normally
>   accessed through the special variables $&, $', $`, $1, $2, and so on.

The important bit is in bold.

You already have *ALL* the matches in a single MatchData object. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: No - you have all captures of a single match in a `MatchData`. If you have multiple matches, you need multiple `MatchData` objects.

Comment: I think this question has the correct answer then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804557/how-do-i-get-the-match-data-for-all-occurrences-of-a-ruby-regular-expression-in

Comment: It's a working answer, but I wouldn't say it's a correct one (from Ruby, not from i-blis). I love Ruby, but this here is a wart.